# How do I start a new dialog following a conversation from an old dialog in Choregraphe?

Tags: dialog, topic-modeling, nao-robot, choregraphe

I'm trying to create a dialog flow in Choregraphe where when the output in the 'Dialog' topic gets triggered (eg. $next=1), a new dialog 'Dialog(1)' gets activated and the new topic can be used by the user.

What happens is the visual on the cable flows to 'Dialog(1)' box, but the bot still only accepts the input patterns from the original topic.

simple example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQ1SU.jpg

How do I make the bot listen to the Dialog(1) topic once the 'next' output is triggered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must change the nature of the output "next" of the emitting box "dialog" from "punctual" to the "onStopped" type. So the box will be stopped just after emitting.

Right click on the output, then "edit output", then "nature" dropbox.